# Do PWAs already support GPS?

Tags: android, gps, progressive-web-apps, android-gps

We are currently working on a PWA for our clients.

I am very excited about this new technology. Still it seems that there are still some important features missing compared to native Apps.

For us it would be important that we can use GPS and more specifically can turn it on with our PWA if it is currently disabled on the client's device.

According to [this article](https://www.digitalgov.gov/2016/10/13/progressive-web-applications-part-2-pros-cons-and-looking-ahead/) from November, this will not be possible in PWAs.

However, 7 months are a long time and I am just curious if it is now possible to use GPS with a PWA?

Comment: Nobody except the TLA's and criminals wants GPS turned on remotely.  Such a feature is not 'progress' :(

Comment: turned on by users approval obviously...

Comment: this smells like a Geo-fencing API request.

Answer (score 4):

GPS is supported if the browser supports it and if the user allows the browser to look up the users location.  If this feature isnt baked in, Google would've been in a lot of trouble.

Check out https://whatwebcando.today to see what your device supports.